# self.scene.view.paused = YES within update

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making a game in which when 2 objects (object A and B) collide, the game gets over. Object A's position changes each time update is called. Object B's position is the same. The code is:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"objA" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([objB intersectsNode:node])
    {

        [node removeFromParent];
        [self GameOver];

    }
```

The problem is: I want objA NOT to disappear after the collision. So, for that I removed     `[node removeFromParent];` , but since update is called again and again. My number of nodes increases and the sound that i have added never seems to end. So, what i tried was adding:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(pauseGame) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.1];

-(void) pauseGame
{
self.scene.view.paused = YES;

[self performSelector:@selector(gameOver) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.1];   

}
```

I had to use `performSelector` with delay, because putting   `self.scene.view.paused = YES;` within the update wouldn't allow me to go to `gameOver`. However, I do not want any delays! is there a way to do this??

Thanks

Comment: you can use a BOOL in update: this is YES and change position of objA, but when objA and objB collide set this BOOL to NO, so in update: nothing happens

Comment: Since this question is regarding Sprite Kit I removed the misleading cocos2d-x and cocos2d-iphone tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a state variable in your scene which will indicate the current state. 
Use this state to run updates on your scene objects.

For example (pseudocode) :

```
update() 
     if (state == GAME_PLAY) {
         // Update relevant game nodes
     } else if (state ==  GAME_OVER) {
         // Update only what needs to be updated when the game is over
     }
```

This way you do not need to stop your entire scene and add only what is relevant to the current game state

Comment: Thank you. Sorry but i am new to Xcode. Please could you explain  me what do i declare state as?? Do you mean something like this? bool gameOver .. and the in update i can have if (!gameOver) and else if (gameOver) ??

Comment: You are welcome. The state variable can be anything. It can be a boolean indicating gameOver as you wrote or it can be an enum with various states (incase you have more game states like game pause)

Comment: @user3529575 - If the answer solved your question, you should mark is as correct.